# Integral involving Dirac delta composition

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$\int dx \ \ f(g(x)) \ \delta(\alpha-g(x))$$

where $\alpha$ is a constant and $g$ some invertible function.

Here's what I did: a change of variables

$$g(x)=y$$

in order to obtain

$$\int \frac{dy}{\left| g'(g^{-1}(y))\right|} \ \ f(y) \ \delta(\alpha-y)$$

so that the result should be

$$\int dx \ \ f(g(x)) \ \delta(\alpha-g(x)) =\frac{f(\alpha)}{\left| g'(g^{-1}(\alpha))\right|}$$

Is my reasoning correct? If not, how should I proceed?

**Update:**

As Semiclassical pointed out, there are issues with my argument when $g(x)=\alpha$ has more than one solution, but I don't know how to proceed in that case.

Comment: What if $g(x)=\alpha$ has more than one solution? No solutions? (To this end, $g(x)=x^2$ is a useful special case.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Good observation. I actually wouldn't know what to do in that case.

Comment: Taking $g(x)=x^2$, there are two main cases: If $\alpha<0$  then the argument of the Dirac delta never vanishes and so the integral should vanish identically. If $\alpha>0$, then there are two solutions $\pm \sqrt{\alpha}$ and one can write $$\delta(\alpha-g(x))=\delta((x-\sqrt{\alpha})(x+\sqrt{\alpha}))=\delta(x-\sqrt{\alpha})(2\sqrt{\alpha}))+\delta(x+\sqrt{\alpha})(-2\sqrt{\alpha})).$$ (The case of $\alpha=0$ gives $\delta(x^2)$, and I forget what one generally does in that case.)

Comment: Should've been two more left-parens in the very last expression.

Comment: Your result is correct. Since $g$ is assumed *invertible*, the equation $g(x) = \alpha$ has a single root. $g(x) = x^2$ used in the above discussion is not invertible.

Comment: @AlexM. You are right, thanks! Somehow I managed to forget my own condition on $g$... :/